# Como executar método em outro formulário

Tags: c#

Não consigo executar um método do formulário 2 através do botão do formulário 1

Chamo o formulário mas o método não aparece

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //executar
        Form2.metodo();
    }
}
```

com os dois formulários abertos nao funcionou

```
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.metodo();
```

Comment: Sem o código do 'Form2' fica difícil. Mas eu posso supor duas possibilidades.
1. no 'Form2' declare `metodo()` como estático. Eg: `public static void metodo(){}`.
2. instancie a classe `Form2`. Eg:
'private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();  
        f.metodo(); <- chamada do método a partir da instancia. 
    }`

Comment: Onde está declarado o método `metodo`? Coloque na pergunta, ele está publico? Porque se não estiver, não conseguirá acessar mesmo.